# Knife Becoming Unusable By Threatening Someone With It

Tags: sources-mekorot, kashering-kosherization

I have heard that if a knife is used (even for pretend) to threaten someone it is treif to use unless Neitza is done to it (being stabbed in the ground 10 times). Does anybody know of a source for this?

Comment: Perhaps they’re further embellishments on R. Yehuda HaChassid’s warning ([Additions, no. 6](https://he.m.wikisource.org/wiki/צוואת_רבי_יהודה_החסיד#צוואת_רבי_יהודה_החסיד)), which may have origins in a *beraita* in San. ([45b](https://www.sefaria.org/Sanhedrin.45b.5?with=all&lang=bi)).

Comment: *דברים שבלב אינו דברים*

Comment: I heard that such a knife is forever forbidden to be used for Shechita.

Comment: @Rafael it's not דברים שבלב because he is physically threatening just not completing the act.

Comment: Sounds made up to me